# WPF Border for ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I try to use a ComboBox based on ToolBar.ComboBoxStyleKey. It has a flat design.
Control by default does not have a border, i.e., on a white background is only visible icon of ToggleButton.
How can I add border for control when focus isn't on ComboBox?

Thanks!

No focus:

> [image: Combo Box without focus]

Mouse hover:

> [image: Mouse Hover]

Answer (score 1):

There is a Border control in WPF, you could use that to wrap around your ComboBox.

```
<Border Background="GhostWhite" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="1">
    <ComboBox>
        ...
    </CombodBox>
</Border>
```

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-border-control/

You could set the BorderThickness according to if the combobox has the focus or not.

Comment: Thanks! Now I've added border. How can I change BorderThickness when hover or focus on ComboBox?

Comment: If you're using MVVM, bind your thickness to a property and modify the property value in the hover/focus event of your combo box. If you're not using MVVM, give a name to your border and modify its border thickness directly in the event.

Comment: I don't use MVVM. Should I add trigger for combobox? <Border x:Name="brStartType" BorderBrush="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22" Width="224" >
   <ComboBox x:Name="cbStartupType" IsReadOnly="True" Height="22" Margin="0" Width="224" />
</Border>

Comment: Just add an event to your combo box.
 <ComboBox x:Name="cbStartupType" IsReadOnly="True" Height="22" Margin="0" Width="224" GotFocus="cbStartupType_GotFocus" />

Comment: In this case I have to add events for GotFocus, LostFocus and Hover.

Comment: Yep, exactly. Just do one function and call this function for all these events

Answer (score 0):

There are countless options available.

1. Draw a rectangle around the combobox's (x,y) coordinates.
2. Make your own custom combobox as shown in: [CustomCombowithBorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221240/combobox-borderstyle).
3. Add a panel behind it and give the panel a border thus imitating a border.
4. etc....

**EDIT:**

Found that [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408(v=vs.95).aspx) gives an excellent answer as also shown in [ComboBox Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627611/wpf-combobox-styling) .

```
<Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
         <Grid>
            <Border x:Name="ContentPresenterBorder">
               <Grid>
                  <ToggleButton x:Name="DropDownToggle"/>
                  <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" />
                     <TextBlock Text=" " />
                  </ContentPresenter>
               </Grid>
            </Border>
         </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```