# wpf change ComboBox border width programatically

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I change the border width of a combobox programatically.

I tried :
combobox.BorderWidth = ...

but It did not work

Ilan

I found out from your answers the following solution :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyleKey" x:Name="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentPresenterBorder" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Property=BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Property=BorderThickness}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Property=Background}" 
                                CornerRadius="3">
                            <Grid>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="DropDownToggle" />
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Using this style I managed to change the border thickness
But now I have a new problem
The ToggleButton and the ContentPresenter  does not work.
I want them to have the default behavior.
Is there a way to assign the default behavior to them (Something like style="default style")?
Thanks,

Comment: Try the BorderThickness property

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296098/wpf-border-for-combobox

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this,

```
 this.comboBox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 3);
```